# How to run django app on windows server ec2 instance with mysql database and costum domain

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, django-deployment, django-dev-server, django-hosts

I have Copied my files to the server and also setup the domain in the route 53 and also installed the xampp server now
When i try starting the server with the command `Python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`
it gives me the following error
`Error: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

but when i visit the domain it autmatically redirected to
domian.com/dashboard/
and there is all the xampp and apache etc stuff

i tried to run it with out specifying the ip and port the it redirects to the domian/dashboard
i want this to use the xampp server for mysql and run on the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you're using the the in-built Django webserver that is meant for development purposes but not the best for production follow the steps below  Deploy Django Applications on windows server using XAMPP

Prerequisite: make sure that your project already have a virtual environment, and you copied your project folder into C:\xampp\htdocs.

also you might need windows 10 sdk installed.

Step 1:

first we should set mod wsgi apache rootdir to our xampp apache directory , so in you cmd type:

> set “MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=c:\xampp\apache”

Step 2:

activate your project environment

Step 3:

In your virtual environment type:

> pip install mod_wsgi

Step 4:

then type this:

> mod_wsgi-express module-config

the output result should be something like this:

> LoadFile “c:/python37–32/python37.dll” LoadModule wsgi_module
> “c:/python37–32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd”
> WSGIPythonHome “c:/python37–32”

Step 5:

open http.conf file and copy to LoadFile and LoadModule from previous step on it

Step 6:

copy this lines in http.conf too:

> #path to wsgi.py file #the first “/ “ indicates the root url
>
> WSGIScriptAlias /
> “C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project_folder/your_project/wsgi.py”
>
> #the one that you get from step 4
>
> WSGIPythonHome “c:/python37–32”
>
> #website path
>
> WSGIPythonPath “C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project_folder”
>
> #directory of website
>
> <Directory “C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project_folder/your_project”>
>
> Require all granted

Step 7:

Restart your xampp and enjoy

You may also find more details on this [post](https://anahita-esfandiaryfard.medium.com/deploy-djnago-on-windows-using-xampp-dc7e85d5e770)

Comment: thank you soo much i used rds and  my problem solved but thanks because this is also working method